# Parameter count mismatch when trying to generate excel from csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, csv

I'm trying to generate a Excel file from CSVfiles. I have different CSV files and I would like to read them and generate a EXCEL file

I've been trying to use the EPPlus library to write the excel. I always have the same problem : **Parameter count mismatch**

So this is my code :

```
public static IActionResult ExelWriter([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {

       IEnumerable<List<string>> list = getData();

       string excelFileName2 = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\exelreader\testF4" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
        string worksheetsName = "Sheet1";
        bool firstRowIsHeader = false;
        var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        format.Delimiter = ',';
        format.EOL = "\r"; 

        using (ExcelPackage package2 = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName2)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package2.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
            worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(list); *this line gives me error*
            package2.Save();
        }
        return null;
    }

 public static IEnumerable<List<string>> getData()
    {
        string csvFileName = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\exelreader\testcsv.csv";
        List<List<string>> rows = new List<List<string>>();
        string value;
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(csvFileName))
        {
            var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            while (csv.Read())
                {
                    List<string> row = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out value); i++)
                    {
                        if (csv.GetField(i) == null)
                        {
                            row.Add("");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Add(Convert.ToString(csv.GetField(i)));
                        }
                    }

                    if (row.Any())
                    {
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<List<string>> a = rows.AsEnumerable();
        return a;
    }
```

I expect to get a full valid excel document. Any idea on why I have such an error, because I don't get it why I get the error when the parameter is excatly of the same type.

** PS : I get the error on run time, not on compile time. **

Thanks :)

Comment: *...the parameter is excatly of the same type*   It is not saying there is a datatype mismatch, it is saying the ***number*** of parameters do not match

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp how is that possible? I requires one parameter, and I give it only one. Also when I give one empty collection of type **IEnumerable<List<string>>** it seems to work. I don't get it. And why is it a run time error and not a compile time?

Comment: Does the CSV have same number of columns in each row.  Excel is probably using first row (which doesn't have header) to determine the number of columns.  If other rows have more data than an error may occur.

Comment: I've dealt with this before by setting the number of output columns to the largest number of columns in the input.  (When this is not known ahead of time...)

Comment: @jdweng The csv has the same columns for every row.  Actually some rows have fewer columns than the first row. Do you think that this might be the same case? The same problem? Any idea? Maybe you can test my code on your pc :)

Comment: @pcalkins Hello, can you explain me how can I achieve this? I didn't get your answer. Maybe You can show me your example or you can try my code :)

Comment: I should of said more or less columns.  The error is due to the some rows having less data than others.  If you query has three parameters and there is only two columns of data you can get errors.  The best solution is to test row (List<string>) and if it contains less that the max number of columns add an empty string.

Comment: Hey @jdweng I think I already did that at thiis line : `if (csv.GetField(i) == null || csv.GetField(i) == ";"){row.Add("");} ` .. Any other idea?

Comment: I did not say null.  I said the difference between the list containing two items and three items.  Two items in a CSV is "A;B" while three items is "A;B;C".  When you split (which is probably done in the csv library) it is splitting the semicolon and removing the semicolon.   So when the row is short you will get a list item that contains two items instead of three in my example.  There is no semicolon.  You may be getting an empty string depending on the library with three items.

Comment: I've only used NPOI (with CSVFileReader's readAll method), so this may not be your issue, but basically you want to standardize your list so that each row has the same number of fields.  To get the max number, loop through rows and set a "maxint" to count the number of fields for each row.  If the next row has more, set maxint to it's count.  Then loop through your list and add blank values if necessary.  Technically the first line of a csv file should set a standard for the number of fields, but you may have an odd one there.

Comment: from the examples I checked it seems like LoadFromCollection is designed to take a List of a class with named properties, so mayyybe that's the real issue.  I think it has some logic for using the property names as column names.  There is also a LoadFromArrays method that I found an example of here, and you can see they're still using named objects:  https://gist.github.com/MikeHook/1132183  In your case might be better to just switch to NPOI